# Can I run Angular-U/UI-Router with Notepad++?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is there some way to run UI-Router without running bower/npm, etc?

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

I tried linking to it (just like to angular), but that didn't work. Tried saving it locally in a .js file and referencing it. That didn't work either. Am I missing something or am I just trying to do something impossible?

edit: Alternatively, is there anywhere to test this? Like plunkr or something?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the source for what I think is the latest.  I think you should just be able to link to it in a `<script />` tag in your `index.html`:

http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js

Or copy that to a text file and run it completely locally, since I think you're just trying to test it out.  If it didn't work, maybe make sure you have all of its dependencies, if any.

Of course it looks like it's a package in plunkr, so you should be able to try it there.  I added it and the latest angular for you (haven't tested it though):

http://plnkr.co/edit/jdX6pRn6noHh1JoP5CH6?p=catalogue

Comment: I tried it in plunkr before and it didn't work, trying again, thank you. Will let you know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can write Angular UI routing code into your Notepad++ editor, But you require a normal web server to run it properly.

You can try the Google Chrome Plugin to execute all AngularJS related codes. 
Kindly Run all the applications using a local server. There is no need for Tomcat server. You can easily download a Google Chrome Plugin "Web server for Chrome". here- [Web Server for Google Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb?hl=en)

Also the Angular UI routing Snippet is available at: https://github.com/TheAjinkya/AngularSnippets/tree/master/Angular%20UI-Router